# Set Tooltip depending on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I want to set the tooltip of my textbox depending on the selected ComboBox value

This is my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LandComboBox" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 1.2." IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 55" />
</ComboBox>
```

And this is my TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="LandTextBox" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Test 1.2.">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hello 1.2." />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Test 55">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hello 55" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

But no tooltip appears. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the binding to `SelectedItem.Content` instead of `SelectedItem`.

The elements in the combobox arent plain `String` "Items".
They are of the type `ComboBoxItem`

```
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Test 1.2.">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hello 1.2." />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Test 55">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hello 55" />
        </DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use : **Path=SelectedItem.Content**

```
<TextBox x:Name="LandTextBox" >
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Test 1.2.">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hello 1.2." />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Test 55">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Hello 55" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `SelectionBoxItem` instead of `SelectedItem`
and you cant use `Value="{Binding ElementName=LandComboBox, Path=SelectionBoxItem}"` also for show dynamically tool-tip